# want to convert the class information of segmented image to node (i.e graph vertex) information in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am doing MS research and i want to implement the cell-graph technique. i have read it and the paper i am implementing title is "**The cell graphs of cancer**". what i am not getting is that they say after segmentation we have a binary image. 1 black shows cell information and 0 white shows background. they apply a grid on that image of size four pixel and threshold value of 0.25 on applying that grid and under the grid pixels are averaged that 1 and 0 for probability of being cell and obtain node information. what i am not getting is how they then transform image into node information? suppose image size is 400x400 what will be the size and shape of node information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'grid' you mention is an image filter which yields a new image where each pixel is 1 where it detects a cell and 0 where no cell is detected.
After that they will use some further processing, image segmentation, blob analysis, bwlabel, regionprops etc, to determine the number, and size and shape of the cells. Have a look at

http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/11/06/segmenting-coinsa-tutorial-on-blob-analysis/

Edit: here is the paper:
http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/20/suppl_1/i145.full.pdf+html

In answer to your questions about the node information - it is in the form of a 2d image, same size as the input:

> The next step is to translate the class information obtained in Step 1
>   to node information of a cell graph ...  At the end of this step, the
>   spatial information of the cells is translated to their locations in
>   the two-dimensional grid ... This step can also be considered as
>   downsampling of an image... ... In the last step, we set the links
>   between the nodes found in Step 2 to generate a graph (Fig. 2f ).  We
>   make use of the Waxman model ... the distance between the nodes
>   (hence, the link probability) describes the prevalence of cancer

This goes right up to fig 2f in the paper. Then in step 3:

> After obtaining the cell graph, we define cell-graph metrics for each
>   node to quantify their cell-network characteristics including cell
>   degree, clustering coefficient and eccentricity... whether a given
>   node of a graph is cancerous, healthy, or inflamed.

So in step 3 they will have a list of x,y pairs for the location of each node and all the other necessary parameters.

Comment: i knew that already what you have said but what my question is a bit different i have to implement cell-graph method in which the actually downsample the image by introduction grid over but it isnt a filter its actually they divide image into small grids and then they take out node information what i am not getting is how they get and store node information is it in the same image form or its shape or size is alot?

Comment: Ah. By downsample you mean reduce color depth.. Eg from an 8 bit image to a 1 bit / black& white image. Can you link to the paper? 'Node information' is quite vague unless we can see more details.

Comment: yes sure. its not opening with me right now but here is its complete citation:
C. Gunduz, B. Yener, and S.H. Gultekin, "The cell-graphs of cancer," Bioinformatics, 20(Suppl 1):i145-i151, 2004.